# Jquery Validation Plugin working in Chrome, but not in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-validate, mozilla

I have a form in a Django application whose validation works perfectly on Chrome, but I can't get it to work on Mozilla.
I load this version of jquery and jquery validation plugin

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

My jquery validation code looks like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneValidator", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^\+?\d?\(?([\d]{3}?)\)?-?([\d]{3}?)-?([\d]{4,5})$/.test(value);
}, 'Please enter a valid phone number. E.g. 123-456-7890');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("zipValidator", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /(?i)^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\- ]{0,10}[a-z0-9]$/.test(value);
}, 'Please enter a valid zip code. E.g. 80111 or 1234-80111');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateValidator", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/|-](0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])[\/|-]([1-9]\d{3})$/.test(value);
}, jQuery.validator.format('Please enter a valid date in mm/dd/yyyy format.'));

jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateNotInFutureValidator", function(value, element) {
  //replace all dashes with /
  value = value.replace(/-/g, '\/');
  value = value.split('/');
  var today = new Date();
  var month = today.getMonth() + 1; //getMonth is 0-indexed
  var day = today.getDate();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  // console.log(month, day, year);
  // console.log(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
  return this.optional(element) || (value[2] == year && value[0] == month && value[1] <= day) || (value[2] == year && value[0] < month) || (value[2] < year);
}, jQuery.validator.format('Please enter a date that is not in the future.'));

jQuery.validator.addMethod("allChars", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);
}, 'This field may only contain characters.');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("allHebrew", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[\u0590-\u05FF]+$/.test(value);
}, 'This field may only contain Hebrew characters.');

FORM_RULES = {
    verify_email: { equalTo: '#id_email' },
    '{{soldier.date_of_birth.name }}' : {'dateValidator': true, 'dateNotInFutureValidator':true},
    '{{soldier.legal_first_name.name}}' : 'allChars',
    '{{soldier.legal_last_name.name}}' : 'allChars',
    '{{soldier.naaleh_selah_choice.name}}' : {
        required: function(element){
            return $('#id_naaleh_selah_bool_0').val() == 1
        }},
    accept_checkbox: {required: true}
};

FORM_MESSAGES = {
    verify_email: {equalTo: 'Please enter the same value as the Email field.'},
    accept_checkbox: {required: 'You must accept the terms and conditions to continue.'}
};


    $('#intake_form').validate({
        rules: FORM_RULES,
        messages: FORM_MESSAGES,
        errorPlacement: function(error, element)
        {

            if ( element.is(":radio"))
            {
                error.insertAfter( element.parent().parent().parent() );
            }
            else if (element.attr("id") === "accept_checkbox")
            {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
            else { // This is the default behavior of the script
                error.insertAfter( element );
            }
        }
    });
```

None of the validation messages are showing up for me on Mozilla Firefox and it lets me submit the form without filling in the required fields.
I do see the following error in the console on Mozilla:

```
SyntaxError: invalid regexp group
```

but I'm not sure what do with it as it says the error is at 1:1:1 - a blank line in the html page source.
I did read somewhere that lookbehind regex syntax is not supported in Firefox and jquery validation plugin does allow usage of regexs, so maybe the two are not compatible?  Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Troubleshooting?  Where is the HTML markup as it appears in the DOM?  Where is the JavaScript as it's rendered in the DOM?  What are `allChars`, `dateValidator`, and `dateNotInFutureValidator` supposed to represent?  Those are not standard jQuery Validate rules.  And if you have a JavaScript syntax error, that's going to be a problem for all the JavaScript on the page.

Comment: Just added a code snippet to my question above. Thank you.

Comment: The Code Snippet feature is pointless if you don't put it together so we can run it.   Please read this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Take the time to condense the code down into the bare minimum that still shows the issue.   Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be working for me in Firefox:  https://jsfiddle.net/vuqes750/  One thing I noticed and fixed is broken HTML.  You are missing at least one closing `</div>` tag.  The validation plugin will break if you don't have valid HTML, especially if the `<form></form>` container is botched up by improperly nested tags such as `div`s left open.  If that doesn't fix it, then you're going to have to take the time to condense the code and create a better demo... there's just way too much superfluous code dumped here.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that my zipValidator (second method call in the validation code posted) had a regex that Firefox considered invalid. Other browsers support the `(?i)` notation (case-insensitive), but Firefox does not.
Once I changed that regex (just added A-Z after every a-z), all the validation and showing and hiding with jquery works.